# How to make Bootstrap rows after an image with more under them without breaking the responsiveness

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

It's hard to explain this with words but once you take a look at the code and the images below they are pretty self-explanatory.

I'm working with Bootstrap 4.4.1 and if you take a look at the code I have something like this:
[image: code that i have currently]

I want to do this:
[image: how i want it to be]

Possibly adding one more row too so that after the image there's three rows, I could probably change positions and margins/etc... to do it but I really don't want to break the responsiveness, there's gotta be a "right way" to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

**[CODE](https://codepen.io/DarkCeptor44/pen/LYEyLoQ)**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h2><span>Student</span></h2>
      <hr/>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group img-responsive">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.imgur.com/374Ggqw.jpg" alt="Student" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <span id="modal-aluno-nome2">Student</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Birthdate</label>
            <span id="modal-aluno-data-nascimento">00/00/0000</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Test</label>
            <span>Test</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Test</label>
            <span>Test</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS (SCSS):**

```
.modal-container {
  transition: 1s ease;
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: auto;

  & > .modal-content {
    background: #fff;
    width: 70%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 7% auto;
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;

    .img-responsive {
      width: 100%;
      max-height: 400px;

      & > img {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1.2px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
    }

    h2 {
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 3em;
      & > span {
        display: inline-block;
      }
    }

    .form-group > label {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      display: flex;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    // For testing purposes
    .row .col-lg-3 {
      //background:red;
      //border:1.2px solid yellow;
      //height:30%;

      .img-responsive {
        //height:100%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the same element below it in the same column.
For example if your 2nd column looks like this:

```
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <span id="modal-aluno-nome2">Student</span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Try changing it to this:

```
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <span id="modal-aluno-nome2">Student</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <span id="modal-aluno-nome2">Student</span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Just duplicate the contents inside of it such as :

```
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <span id="modal-aluno-nome2">Student</span>
          </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is perfect. Also sorry for being 8h late.